# setState with return in TYPESCRIPT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-tsx

Oops, my friends, I have this "problem" when using setState, as setState is not asynchronous I can't use it the way I want. I set the value and when calling the function to send back the value returns with "delay".
How do I resolve this?

```html
  const [quantityProduct, setQuantityProduct] = useState<number>(0);

function addQuantity() {
    var soma = Number(quantityProduct) + 1;
    setQuantityProduct(soma);
    sendProduct()
}
  
function sendProduct() {
    console.log(quantityProduct)
}
```

Comment: you want to use updated value of `quantityProduct` in function **sendProduct**, do you?

Comment: use useEffect with a dependency of quantityProduct

Comment: This isn't a question about Typescript - it's about how React deals with async state updates.

Comment: @Andy, in javascript it is possible to use this syntax, " this.setState({ title: event.target.value }, function() {
     this.validateTitle();
   });" in the typescript I can't use this syntax

Comment: @RodineiCirineu That's not true. You're comparing class based state syntax with hooks syntax. It has nothing to do with typescript.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the following two lines are asynchronous. What you experience is the second line gets executed before completing the first one.

```
setQuantityProduct(soma);
sendProduct();
```

You meant to call `sendProduct` when the `quantityProduct` gets updated. You should be using `useEffect` hook with `quantityProduct` in the dependency array.

Try like below.

```
  const [quantityProduct, setQuantityProduct] = useState<number>(0);
  function addQuantity() {
    var soma = Number(quantityProduct) + 1;
    setQuantityProduct(soma);
  }

  function sendProduct() {
    console.log(quantityProduct);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    sendProduct();
  }, [quantityProduct]);
```

2nd way: calling the API inside `setState` callback

```
  function addQuantity() {
    setQuantityProduct((prevQuantity) => {
      var newQuantity = Number(prevQuantity) + 1;
      sendProduct(newQuantity);
      return newQuantity;
    });
  }
```

Comment: useEffect is the only way? is it not possible to have some return in setState when it has updated to send the sendProduct request?

Comment: This is the usual way of doing it. But, if you do it inside the callback of setState and before the return statement it will also work.

Comment: Could you show me some example of the setState callback syntax?
I saw several examples in Javascript, but with Typescript I didn't find

Answer (score 1):

"setState is not asynchronous"

This isn't true. [The documentation is clear on this](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous):

> React may batch multiple setState() calls into a single update for performance. Because this.props and this.state may be updated asynchronously, you should not rely on their values for calculating the next state.

You need to use the [`useEffect` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) to watch for changes in state (passing in the state you want to watch in a dependency array), and then perform an operation based on that change.

```js
const [quantityProduct, setQuantityProduct] = useState(0);

function addQuantity() {
  const soma = Number(quantityProduct) + 1;
  setQuantityProduct(soma);
}

function sendProduct() {
  console.log(quantityProduct);
}

useEffect(() => {
  sendProduct();
}, [quantityProduct]);
```